# R error, package 'colorspace', scale_fill_continuous_diverging() does not work in functions while scale_color_continuous_diverging() does

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've run into a problem while programming with the package 'colorspace'. If I use the function scale_fill_continuous_diverging() within another function it does not find the argument input I provide in the 'parent function'. If I have an object named like the argument in my global environment it takes this instead and then it works. If I, however, do not have an object named like the argument it crashes. This problem does not appear while working with scale_**color**_continous_diverging(). I add an example below.

Does anybody know what is going on here and especially how to fix this? I'd prefer not to mess with the global environment of the user so working with assign(..., envir = .GlobalEnv) is not an option.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(colorspace)

# create example data 
df <-
  mutate(mtcars, example_var = seq(-1, 1, length.out = nrow(mtcars)))

# save object in global environment
clrsp <- "Berlin"

# plot outside of functions -> works in both cases
ggplot(df, aes(x = qsec, y = wt, color = example_var)) +
  geom_point(size = 6) +
  colorspace::scale_color_continuous_diverging(palette = clrsp)

ggplot(df, aes(x = qsec, y = wt, fill = example_var)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, size = 6) +
  colorspace::scale_fill_continuous_diverging(palette = clrsp)

# remove object from global environment
rm(clrsp)

# write functions
plot_example_color <- function(df, clrsp){

  p <-
    ggplot(df, aes(x = qsec, y = wt, color = example_var)) +
    geom_point(size = 6) +
    colorspace::scale_color_continuous_diverging(palette = clrsp)

  return(p)

}

plot_example_fill <- function(df, clrsp){

  p <-
    ggplot(df, aes(x = qsec, y = wt, fill = example_var)) +
    geom_point(shape = 21, size = 6) +
    colorspace::scale_fill_continuous_diverging(palette = clrsp)

  return(p)

}

# color aesthetic works...
plot_example_color(df = df, clrsp = "Berlin")

# ...fill does not
plot_example_fill(df = df, clrsp = "Berlin")

# add clrsp to global environment
clrsp <- "Blue-Red 2"

# works but with the one from the global environment
plot_example_fill(df = df, clrsp = "Berlin")
```

Comment: this might be a bug with how objects in environments are handled, see http://colorspace.r-forge.r-project.org/contact.html on how to report a bug

Comment: Alright, will do! Thank you for posting the link.